# could not bind socket while haproxy restart

Tags: haproxy

I m restarting HAproxy by following command

```
haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)
```

but i get following message

```
[ALERT] 183/225022 (9278) : Starting proxy appli1-rewrite: cannot bind socket
[ALERT] 183/225022 (9278) : Starting proxy appli2-insert: cannot bind socket
[ALERT] 183/225022 (9278) : Starting proxy appli3-relais: cannot bind socket
[ALERT] 183/225022 (9278) : Starting proxy appli4-backup: cannot bind socket
[ALERT] 183/225022 (9278) : Starting proxy ssl-relay: cannot bind socket
[ALERT] 183/225022 (9278) : Starting proxy appli5-backup: cannot bind socket
```

my haproxy.cfg file looks likefollowing

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1    local0
    log 127.0.0.1    local1 notice
    #log loghost    local0 info
    maxconn 4096
    #chroot /usr/share/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    #debug
    #quiet

defaults
    log    global
    mode    http
    option    httplog
    option    dontlognull
    retries    3
    option redispatch
    maxconn    2000
    contimeout    5000
    clitimeout    50000
    srvtimeout    50000

listen    appli1-rewrite 0.0.0.0:10001
    cookie    SERVERID rewrite
    balance    roundrobin
    server    app1_1 192.168.34.23:8080 cookie app1inst1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
    server    app1_2 192.168.34.32:8080 cookie app1inst2 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
    server    app1_3 192.168.34.27:8080 cookie app1inst3 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
    server    app1_4 192.168.34.42:8080 cookie app1inst4 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

listen    appli2-insert 0.0.0.0:10002
    option    httpchk
    balance    roundrobin
    cookie    SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server    inst1 192.168.114.56:80 cookie server01 check inter 2000 fall 3
    server    inst2 192.168.114.56:81 cookie server02 check inter 2000 fall 3
    capture cookie vgnvisitor= len 32

    option    httpclose        # disable keep-alive
    rspidel ^Set-cookie:\ IP=    # do not let this cookie tell our internal IP address

listen    appli3-relais 0.0.0.0:10003
    dispatch 192.168.135.17:80

listen    appli4-backup 0.0.0.0:10004
    option    httpchk /index.html
    option    persist
    balance    roundrobin
    server    inst1 192.168.114.56:80 check inter 2000 fall 3
    server    inst2 192.168.114.56:81 check inter 2000 fall 3 backup

listen    ssl-relay 0.0.0.0:8443
    option    ssl-hello-chk
    balance    source
    server    inst1 192.168.110.56:443 check inter 2000 fall 3
    server    inst2 192.168.110.57:443 check inter 2000 fall 3
    server    back1 192.168.120.58:443 backup

listen    appli5-backup 0.0.0.0:10005
    option    httpchk *
    balance    roundrobin
    cookie    SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server    inst1 192.168.114.56:80 cookie server01 check inter 2000 fall 3
    server    inst2 192.168.114.56:81 cookie server02 check inter 2000 fall 3
    server    inst3 192.168.114.57:80 backup check inter 2000 fall 3
    capture cookie ASPSESSION len 32
    srvtimeout    20000

    option    httpclose        # disable keep-alive
    option  checkcache        # block response if set-cookie & cacheable

    rspidel ^Set-cookie:\ IP=    # do not let this cookie tell our internal IP address

    #errorloc    502    http://192.168.114.58/error502.html
    #errorfile    503    /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile    400    /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile    403    /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile    408    /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile    500    /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile    502    /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile    503    /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile    504    /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
```

what is wrong with my aproach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. You aren't running as root; probably needs a `sudo` in front of your command to start it on the command line if you aren't running as root (check with `whoami`).
2. Another process, likely another instance of HAProxy, is already bound to those ports.  Check with `netstat -apn`.

Comment: I am running this command from python via ssh root login and I get this error but not if i do it directly as root or ssh agent from tty

Answer (score 11):

On RedHat Linux with enabled SELinux (which should be enabled), just enable the **haproxy_connect_any** boolean value, which allows haproxy to connect the socket to any port:

```
setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any on
```

Comment: I guess a better approach would be [Creating Custom SELinux Policy Modules with audit2allow](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#Creating_Custom_SELinux_Policy_Modules_with_audit2allow)

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the better way. But way better than just disable selinux…

Comment: If you're deploying into prod (or setting up a staging env or something like prod), definitely do the audit2allow approach instead.  If you're screwing around in dev, this sebool way is pretty nice.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is because of selinux
I type

```
setenforce 0
```

and solve the problem.
The command is to make selinux to premissive mode. A not proper set selinux may block many service or connection.

Comment: Can you expand on what the command does and why it solves the problem?

Comment: I think the default selinux setting block my service, because once I set the selinux to premissive mode, every thing goes well.

Comment: Is this need to be done at each boot ?

Comment: While this can be used as a quick method of determining if SELinux is the problem, disabling SELinux is a very insecure way to solve this kind of problem. Much better to find out exactly _why_ SELinux is blocking the behavior and modifying the SELinux configuration appropriately.

Comment: https://stopdisablingselinux.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the process id in /var/run/haproxy.pid is the same as the currently running instance of HAProxy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue is with your IO address or port. Please verify that your public IP is properly configured. You can check it by running the commands below:

```
ifconfig 
ip addr
```